# SQLite select row with multiple condition from other table

Tags: sqlite

I'm having probleme with a SQL request.
I have two tables:

- main table is

> ```
> Id | Name
> 1  | Name_1
> 2  | Name_2
> ```

- keyword table

> ```
> Id | _mainId | key  
> 1  |    1    | kw1  
> 2  |    1    | kw2  
> 3  |    1    | kw3  
> 4  |    2    | kw2  
> 5  |    2    | kw4
> ```

I would like a request which return the Id and Name of the mane table with all the keywords selected

something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.Id), t1.Name 
FROM       main t1 
INNER JOIN keywords t2 ON t2._Main = t1.Id 
WHERE      t2.keyword = 'kw2' AND  t2.keyword = 'kw4';
```

Comment: sqllite or mysql?

Comment: How do we know what `all the keywords` means?

Comment: @McNets it's SQLite.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen weywords are base on building classes like structure, Achitecture.

Comment: `WHERE      t2.keyword = 'kw2' AND  t2.keyword = 'kw4';` will always return false. Use `OR` or `IN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query below, the subquery aliased as `t2` identifies all IDs having both the keywords `'kw2'` and `'kw4'`.  I then join the `main` table to this subquery to bring in the name information for those matching IDs.

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name
FROM main t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT _mainId
    FROM keywords
    WHERE keyword IN ('kw2', 'kw4')
    GROUP BY _mainId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT keyword) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.Id = t2._mainId
```

Comment: it's working great ! thx !
Just a question, if i want to use more than 2 keywords, i change  "2" by the number of keywords ?

Comment: @Thibaud Yes, just change `2` to match the number of target keywords in the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.Id, t1.Name
FROM
  main t1
  INNER JOIN keywords t2 ON t2._mainId=t1.Id
WHERE
  t2.key IN ('kw2', 'kw4');
```